# generating a regular expression from a string

Tags: java, regex

I wish to generate a regular expression from a string containing numbers, and then use this as a Pattern to search for similar strings. Example:

```
String s = "Page 3 of 23"
```

If I substitute all digits by `\d`

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        sb.append("\\d"); // backslash d
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());

//    Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("Page \d of \d\d");
```

I can use this to match similar strings (e.g. `"Page 7 of 47"`). My problem is that if I do this naively some of the metacharacters such as `(){}-`, etc. will not be escaped. Is there a library to do this or an exhaustive set of characters for regular expressions which I must and must not escape? (I can try to extract them from the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) but am worried about missing something).

Alternatively is there a library which already does this (I don't at this stage want to use a full Natural Language Processing solution).

NOTE: @dasblinkenlight's edited answer now works for me!

Comment: Here's an answer to the which characters question, I'm not aware of any libraries to generate regexs though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @Evan thanks. I am only interested in Java so that looks like a useful resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java's regexp library provides this functionality:

```
String s = Pattern.quote(orig);
```

The "quoted" string will have all its metacharacters escaped. First, escape your string, and then go through it and replace digits by `\d` to make a regular expression. Since regex library uses `\Q` and `\E` for quoting, you need to enclose your portion of regex in inverse quotes of `\E` and `\Q`.

One thing I would change in your implementation is the replacement algorithm: rather than replacing character-by-character, I would replace digits in groups. This would let an expression produced from `Page 3 of 23` match strings like `Page 13 of 23` and `Page 6 of 8`.

```
String p = Pattern.quote(orig).replaceAll("\\d+", "\\\\E\\\\d+\\\\Q");
```

This would [produce](http://ideone.com/fvo6V9) `"\QPage \E\d+\Q of \E\d+\Q\E"` no matter what page numbers and counts were there originally. The output needs only one, not two slashes in `\d`, because the result is fed directly to regex engine, bypassing the Java compiler.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this method.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Great! Agreed I might look for repeated digits but there is also heuristics value for me in having exact digit counts. I may use both approaches.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust See the last edit: the number of slashes required to make two slashes in the output is really ridiculous - times two for the compiler and times two for the regex library, for the total of eight slashes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight. Which is why I am grateful to you for creating it! Takes me a long time to get the number right! (I tend to use constants to help break it down)

Comment: I think this answer has everything I need and can be extended so I have accepted it

Comment: NOTE: I was surprised by the output. `Pattern.quote("3 - 45")` gives `\Q3 - 45\E` . This is quoting the whole string. I am not sure whether this would not then destroy the replacements

Comment: @peter.murray.rust That's why I wrote that you need to first escape the string, and only then go through with the replacements.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So \Q ... \E doesn't turn off matching against \\d+ for example?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust You're right, it will... Let me look into this to see if there's something better that may work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I like the current solution. I will test it now

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I find I need  `replaceAll("\\d+", "\\\\E\\\\d+\\\\Q")`;