# Using patern matcher to extract html

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a pice of HTML:

```
<div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 2.3  </div>
```

(This is the version of my app in the play store) What i am trying to do, is get the latest version using Pattern matching.

what i have thus far for matching the pattern is:

```
String htmlString = "Some very long webpage string that includes the above tag"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("softwareVersion\"> [^ <]*</dd");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Html);
matcher.find();
```

How do i now go about extractin `2.3` from the htmlString?

Comment: This is not a useful answer, but just as a warning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/674108

Comment: Yeah, you should use a proper parser

Comment: In general, parse HTML with an HTML parser. Regardless of that, that expression won't match because you have spaces before the `<`. And you should familiarize yourself with [capturing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16038206/4125191).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using JSoup xhtml parser

It's well known that you **should not parse xhtml with regex** unless you know the html character set you are going to parse. You should use a xhtml parser instead like JSoup. So, you could use something like this:

```
 String htmlString = "YOUR HTML HERE";
 Document document=Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
 Element element=document.select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first();
 System.out.println(element.text());
```

### Regex approach

However, if you want to use regex, then you have to use capturing groups and then grab its content.

```
String htmlString = "Some very long webpage string that includes the above tag"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("softwareVersion\"> ([^ <]*)</dd");
                                               //     ^------^ Here
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture it in a capture group?

("softwareVersion\"> ([^ <]*)< /dd");

Then accessing the value with matcher.group(1)

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak a few things to make this work:

```
String htmlString = "String that includes <div class=\"content\" itemprop=\"softwareVersion\"> 2.3  </div>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("softwareVersion\"> ([^ <]*) +</div");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
//else??
```

The `()` in the RE make it possible to use `matcher,group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

First, as comments point out, you can't parse HTML with a regex (thanks to Jeff Burka for linking to the canonical answer).

Second, since you are looking at a very limited and particular situation you can match using a capturing group to get the version.

Assuming that the div in question is not broken across lines, my strategy would be much like your posted attempt; look for the string *softwareVersion* and the tag close `>` character, optional whitespace, the version string, optional whitespace, and the closing tag.

That gives a regex like `softwareVersion[^>]*>\s*([0-9.]+)\s*</`

From debuggex (which needs the `.*` to match the leading part):

```
.*softwareVersion[^>]*>\s*([0-9.]+)\s*</
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Pdr11u0LvHdHiOT4)

This will give you the version in a capturing group, which will be `matcher.group(1)`

As a Java string, that's `softwareVersion[^>]*>\\s*([0-9.]+)\\s*</`

---

I omitted the `div` after `</` because, while it's in a div now, maybe it'll be a span or something else in the future.
I went simple with `[0-9.]` so it can match `2.3` but also `3.0.1`, however it would also match `..382.1...33` — you could make one that matches a limited or arbitrary set of `n(.n)*` dotted numbers if it was important.

---

`softwareVersion[^>]*>\\s*([1-9][0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+){0,3})\\s*</` matches a version number *n* with zero to three *.n* point releases, so 3.0.2.1 but not 1.2.3.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex `\"softwareVersion\">\s([0-9].?[0-9]?+)\s\s<\/div>`:

```
\" matches the character " literally
softwareVersion matches the characters softwareVersion literally (case sensitive)
\" matches the character " literally
> matches the characters > literally
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
1st Capturing group ([0-9].?[0-9]?+)
[0-9] match a single character present in the list below
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
.? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[0-9]?+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: ?+ Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, without giving back [possessive]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
< matches the characters < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
div> matches the characters div> literally (case sensitive)
```

https://regex101.com/r/kR7lC2/1